# Get Geojson list of proprieties with javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

Lets say I have a GeoJson file named 'cities' ("cities.geojson")
Here is an sample of this file :

```
    {"type": "FeatureCollection","name": "cities", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },"features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": { "Id" :"1" , "Name": "OUJ-DK1", "country : morocco", "continent" : "Africa"}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -1.920918, 34.713995, 0.0 ], ... , [ -1.920918, 34.713995, 0.0 ] ] ] ] } }
```

As you see, it has 4 feature proprieties :

Id", "Name", "country", "continent"

I tried uploading the GeoJson file using OpenLayers :

```
my_goejson = new ol.layer.Vector({
title: 'Geojson file',
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: "C:/cities.geojson",
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
}),
style: style,});
```

My aim is to get the list of the proprieties of this file. I mean my goal is to obtain this list below :

["Id", "Name", "country", "continent"]

I already tried this line :

```
console.log(Object.keys(my_goejson.source.properties));
```

But it s not working

Any ideas ?

Comment: The file will not load unless the layer is added to a map, then need to wait for the source's featuresloadend event before there is anything to log.  Most browsers do not allow you to load files from file protocol such as C:, only http or https protocols are supported.  For local files using drag and drop as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html might be a better option.  Once loaded there could be many features, and each might have different properties depending on what the feature represents.  https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-forked-k2s13

Comment: thank you sir but that s not what i meant by the question. I am wondering how to get all the proprieties in a list (assuming that the layer was displayed on the map)

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(my_goejson.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getProperties()));` will show the property names of the first feature.  Other features might have different properties.